# Vite+react (.jsx) with github

Tags: reactjs, github, error-handling, jsx, mime

I get 404,499 and classic MIME error that is

> "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.".

my repo link https://github.com/alperenwebcoding/Portfolio-Website

link of the website: https://alperenweb.com

I tried every single solution on internet and couldn't solve the problem. what should I do?

I tried changing directors, json files, adding base and every single solution on the internet